# Al intentar instalar la librería ChatterBot vía !pip install ChatterBot en google colab aparece el error subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, google-colab

> Collecting ChatterBot
> Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ChatterBot) (0.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0,>=3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ChatterBot) (3.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: pint>=0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ChatterBot) (0.22)
> Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3 (from ChatterBot)
> Using cached pymongo-3.13.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (516 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ChatterBot) (2.7.5)
> Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1 (from ChatterBot)
> Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> error: metadata-generation-failed
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es intentar instalar una versión PyYAML que sea compatible con tu entorno, por ejemplo: !pip install PyYAML==5.1.2
Después de realizar esto, trata de instalar ChatterBot ignorando dependencias: !pip install ChatterBot --no-dependencies
Si esto no funciona, mejor considera realizar un entorno virtual o buscar versiones alternativas a ChatterBot. Te recomiendo checar su documentación.